# Appending Geolocation with Backbone

Tags: javascript, class, backbone.js, geolocation, underscore.js

The goal of my code is to append to an existing element the latitude which I get back from the geolocation object. I usually use something like

```
this.$el.find(".className").method()
```

to do any method in my backbone code. However, as I am creating an if statement with a function inside which looks like this:

```
render: function(){
    if ("geolocation" in navigator){
         navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
              this.$el.find(".className").append(position.coords.latitude)
         })
    }
    else {

    }
}
```

"This" does not return the object I wish to target.
If I do something like: `document.getElementById("idName").append(position.coords.latitude)`

In the line where, in the example, I have this.$el, the code will run locally but when minified will not work (and will not display any errors). I also understand, even if this method did work with minification it is not a good way to write backbone code.

With all this in mind, how would I target the object which I wish to append to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use [_.bind](http://underscorejs.org/#bind):

```
     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
         _.bind(
            function(position) { this.$el.find(".className").append(position.coords.latitude)},
            this
         )
     )
```